# Why a build is succesful even if an identifier is unresolved?

Tags: c, printf, identifier

I have used the instruction snprintf in my code:

```
snprintf(debugstr, sizeof(debugstr), "FW: %s ver %s\r\n", FW_NAME, FW_VERSION);
```

I am using MPLAB IDE with compiler XC16 v1.31 with the option "use legacy libc" enabled in project properties section.
When I build the project I get the message: "BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 104ms)".

However, in the source .c file on the editor pane, when I pass the mouse pointer on the above code line number, it is shown an error message saying: "Unable to resolve identifier snprintf" (pls see enclosed image).[image]

My question is:
is it normal to have a project successful build and at the same time having an unresolved identifier error message? Why?

Thank you for your attention!

G

Comment: Maybe turn on all your compiler warnings? It must be assuming `snprintf()` is a function with no prototype and leaving the job to find it to the linker. **BEWARE** the code the compiler creates with a wrong assumption may be (will be) wrong for interfacing with the pre-compiled library code.

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: BTW: `snprintf()` was introduced with C99, it's possibly unavailable/klonky in C89/C90 implementations.

Comment: Documentation for XC16 ( [link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50002071F.pdf) ) says: "1.3.1 **ANSI C Standard** [...] compiler that conforms to the ANSI C standard as defined by the ANSI specification (ANSI x3.159-1989) [...]" ... so **you have a C89 compiler and a C99 library**. Good luck :-) *I suggest you keep to the C89 subset of the language.*

Comment: Found [this interesting document about C89](https://scc-forge.lancaster.ac.uk/open/char/versions/std-c89) and differences with C95/C99/C11.

Comment: The editor including its code analyzer and the compiler are different beasts, which can diagnose a different set of problems. This leads sometimes to this effect you experience.

Answer (score 1):

from the MAN page for snprintf()

```
snprintf(), vsnprintf():
_XOPEN_SOURCE >= 500 || 
_ISOC99_SOURCE || 
/* Glibc versions <= 2.19: */ _BSD_SOURCE
```

so you need to start your source file with:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

Comment: I thank you much for your answer that sounded quite interesting and promising. But unfortunately it didn't solve the problem, nor by including <stdarg.h> in my source: the "Unable to resolve identifier snprintf" is still there.
What is strange is that the FW seems to work fine in spite of that, and the same instruction on another source file (not the main) does not give any error message!
It is quite annoying (and a bit suspicious) having the project successfully build and in the same time that error message...